# How to ask for an int, then subtract it by 5 in C

Tags: c, loops, integer

I have some completely awful code that needs reworking. I'm in a beginner's C course and can't get my head around looping. Can someone assist me?

```
{
    int partone, answer;

    printf("Please enter an integer, then press enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &partone);

    while (partone > 1)
    {
        answer = partone - 5;
        printf("Let me count backwards... %d.", answer);
    }
    printf("done");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to change `partone` in the loop, for exampke `partone--;`

Comment: ... or `partone -= 5`, which is shorthand for `partone = partone - 5`. Good luck!

Comment: Are you trying to count backwards from the entered number by fives, or are you trying to count backwards from the entered number by ones, but just print the value with five subtracted?

Answer (score 2):

You are never decrementing `partone`, so it will loop forever.

You can either do `partone--` or `partone -= 5` depending by how much you want to decrement.

Comment: OP has a bug in his code, this will go negative if partone starts with 4

Comment: @GIJoe We don not know if it has to stop at 0 but I guess we could assume that.

Comment: I think that's a fair assumption.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `partone` in the loop. Your `answer` variable really isn't necessary:

```
while (partone > 1)
{
    partone -= 5;
    printf("Let me count backwards... %d.", partone);
}
```

Comment: OP has a bug in his code, this will go negative if partone starts with 4.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong variable

```
{
int partone, answer;

printf("Please enter an integer, then press enter: ");
scanf("%d", &partone);

while (answer > 1)
{
    answer = partone - 5;
    printf("Let me count backwards... %d.", answer);
}
printf("done");

return 0;
}
```

Since only `answer` is changing you should put it as condition. But you really don't need it:

```
{
int partone;

printf("Please enter an integer, then press enter: ");
scanf("%d", &partone);

while (partone > 1)
{
    partone -= 5;
    printf("Let me count backwards... %d.", partone);
}
printf("done");

return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
What you are trying to do is completly different than what you have showed:

```
     #include<stdio.h>
int main()
 {
int partone,i;

printf("Please enter an integer, then press enter: ");
scanf("%d", &partone);


    printf("Let me count backwards...");

    for( i=partone;i >= (partone -5); i--)
        {
          printf("%d ", i);


        }



printf("done");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @GIJoe You don't have to downvote just because I forgot to erase something. You would've just said that

Comment: @GIJoe yes but now it is fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OP has a bug in his code, this will go negative if partone starts with 4

Comment: @GIJoe it's ok for a beginner, you can also see a bug when you enter a letter instead of a number.

Comment: How can I get it to count back from five only once, while printing it counting back? i.e. If the user types 20, it prints "20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15"?

Comment: Didn't need "answer" in there anyway, I'm just a moron. ;)

Comment: @pixelpinch check the edit. You should learn more about loops.

Comment: @user689 trying my best, but learning programming through a shoddy online course isn't boding well for me. profs won't help, just say to google it. thanks so much though :)

Comment: @pixelpinch That's because I forgot to add a condition. Did you check the edited code?

Comment: @user689 It's still giving me an infinite loop. ;-;

Comment: @pixelpinch edited my answer, but please you should try your best next time.